# DB2 Suppress 'The command completed with no results returned'

Tags: db2

I'm running SQL scripts on DB2 9.7.0.6 (AIX).
Client is Embacadero's Rapid SQL 7.7

I insert the following code at the beginning of my stored procedure to calculate the date for me.

```
DROP VARIABLE FOLM;

CREATE VARIABLE FOLM CHAR (10);
SET FOLM = (SELECT CURRENT_DATE - (DAY(CURRENT_DATE)-1) DAYS - 1 MONTH
        FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1);
```

When I run the stored proc, the above code produces these three lines before the results of my procedure:

```
The command completed with no results returned
The command completed with no results returned
The command completed with no results returned
```

How can I suppress this?

Comment: Are you getting this output when you *create* the stored procedure, or when you *execute* it?  What 3 statements are being executed that return the message 3 times?

Comment: This occurs when I execute the stored procedure.  What is being executed is the code in the first code-box.

The results are in the second code box.